# What part of speech is 'day' in 'from day one'?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases, parts-of-speech

> It would be off-topic because peeving disguised as a question has been off-topic ***from day one***. And I might add that the way your question is worded right now, it does not even attempt to pretend to know what a disguise is.

As far as I understand ***from day one*** means ***since the very beginning***, but, in English, even in day-by-day speech, is it normal to say ***from day one***? And what part of speech is 'day' in that fragment? Adjective?

Comment: "from day one" = quite common way of saying "since the very beginning"

Answer (score 3):

The word **day** in *day one* is a noun.

The expression **day one** is quite common. This is quite similar to a countdown during a rocket launch, where the last 10 seconds countdown is usually announced *"T-minus 10, 9, 8, ..., 3, 2, 1"*.

Day One usually refers to the first day of some operation or activity. You can even have Day-minus too. For example, the well-known D-Day is June 6, 1944. D-Day Minus One is June 5, 1944. You can say Day One, Day Two, Day Three, and so on.

Also note that you can say *T minus 3 minutes*, *T minus 2 hours*, when you want to specified the minus-time not in seconds. Similarly, you can have **day minus one month**, or in the case of D-Day, *D-Day minus two months*, and so on.

Comment: I agree. This is parallel to the construction “since January”. “January” is a noun and “since” is a preposition; similarly, “day” is a noun and “from” is a preposition that can be used to refer to the beginning of a period of time; as in “from the beginning” or “from 1993 until 1997.”